# How to display jasper resport in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jasper-reports

I have designed jasper report using ireport and i want to call that report from jsp and i have constructed the report using sql query .

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475186/jasper-reports-in-jsp-page & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407704/jasperreports-how-to-dispaly-report-in-jsp-page

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a servlet on click of button or image from your jsp file. In servlet compile your jrxml(jasper report format). And then you need to write a code to download that servlet.

Below code is used to compile jasper report and export in specific folder :

```
HashMap<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        String fileName = "C:\\temp\\report.jrxml"; 
        String pdfFile = "C:\\temp\\";
        JasperReport mainReport;
        JasperDesign mainReportDesign;

        try {
            mainReportDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(fileName);
            mainReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(mainReportDesign);
            if(reportFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("PDF"))
                pdfFile = pdfFile+"report.pdf";
            else if(reportFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("CSV"))
                pdfFile = pdfFile+"report.csv";
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(mainReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());


            if(reportFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("PDF"))
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, pdfFile);
            else if(reportFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("CSV")) {
                JRExporter exporter = new JRCsvExporter();
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, pdfFile);
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
                exporter.exportReport();
            }

        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Below Code is used to download that export file from that folder. This will be in your servlet class :

```
        File  f        = new File("C:\\temp\\report.pdf");
        int                 length   = 0;
        ServletOutputStream op       = resp.getOutputStream();
        ServletContext      context  = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
        String              mimetype = context.getMimeType(f.getName());

        resp.setContentType( (mimetype != null) ? mimetype : "application/octet-stream" );
        resp.setContentLength( (int)f.length() );
        resp.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+reportName );

        byte[] bbuf = new byte[1024];
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));

        while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1))
        {
            op.write(bbuf,0,length);
        }

        in.close();
        op.flush();
        op.close();
```